# Only a part of the updated state is rendered in the component (React/Redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm currently trying out React in combination with Redux and came across a weird problem:

If one property of the state is changed, the view gets updated in the component. If the other property is changed, it doesn't get updated - unless I update the first property again. I'll try to make it more clear:

This is the Store interface:

```
export interface StoreState {
    counter: number;
    rectangles: Rectangle[];
}
```

This is the reducer:

```
export function enthusiasm(state: StoreState, action: EnthusiasmAction): StoreState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM:
            return { ...state, counter: state.counter + 1 };
        case DECREMENT_ENTHUSIASM:
            return { ...state, counter: Math.max(1, state.counter - 1) };
        case ADD_RECTANGLE:
            let updatedRectangles: Rectangle[] = [];
            if(state.rectangles){
                updatedRectangles = state.rectangles;
            }
            updatedRectangles.unshift(action.payload);
            return {...state, rectangles: updatedRectangles};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

This is the container wrapping the component:

```
export function mapStateToProps(state: StoreState) {
    return {
        enthusiasmLevel: state.counter,
        rectangles:state.rectangles,
    }
}

export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<actions.EnthusiasmAction>) {
    return {
        onIncrement: () => dispatch(actions.incrementEnthusiasm()),
        onDecrement: () => dispatch(actions.decrementEnthusiasm()),
        addRectangle: () => dispatch(actions.addRectangle({posX: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), posY: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Hello);
```

This is the component I'm trying to render:

```
function Hello({ counter = 1, rectangles = [], onIncrement, onDecrement, addRectangle }: Props) {
    console.log(counter, rectangles);
    return (
        <div className="hello">
                <button onClick={onDecrement}>-</button>
                <button onClick={onIncrement}>+</button>
                <button onClick={addRectangle}>+</button>
            <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
                <Layer>
                    {
                        rectangles.map((rectangle: Rectangle) => {
                            return <Rect
                                key={rectangle.id}
                                x={rectangle.posX}
                                y={rectangle.posY}
                                width={150}
                                height={150}
                                fill={'green'}
                                draggable
                                onDragStart={handleDragStart}
                                onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
                            />
                        })
                    }
                </Layer>
            </Stage>
        </div>
    );
}
```

When I increment the counter, the view gets updated and the state logged.

[image]

When I call addRectangle, the view doesn't update (and the state isn't logged in the component) even though the state is changed: [image]

Now when I increment the counter again, the view finally gets updated and all rectangles that got added before are added to the view (and the state is logged again):

[image]

Since I'm new to react, the problem might seem pretty obvious, but I just can't figure out what I do wrong. I really appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mutating `state.rectangles` in place. Redux skips rendering if the state is unchanged. You should create a new array instead. This is explained in the redux docs: [Updating nested objects](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/immutableupdatepatterns#updating-nested-objects)

> #### Common Mistake #1: New variables that point to the same objects
>
> Defining a new variable does not create a new actual object - it only
>   creates another reference to the same object.

In this case our problem is that `updatedReactangles` is not a new array.

```js
case ADD_RECTANGLE:
    let updatedRectangles: Rectangle[] = [];
    if(state.rectangles){
        updatedRectangles = state.rectangles;  // still the same array
    }
    updatedRectangles.unshift(action.payload);
    return {...state, rectangles: updatedRectangles};
```

Try something like this instead:

```js
case ADD_RECTANGLE:
    let updatedRectangles: Rectangle[] = [];
    if(state.rectangles){
        updatedRectangles = state.rectangles.slice();  // shallow copy
    }
    updatedRectangles.unshift(action.payload);
    return {...state, rectangles: updatedRectangles};
```

The `...` operator can make this bug easier to avoid. Since there's no mutating methods such as `Array.unshift()` involved, we can be sure that we are not unintentionally messing with the previous state.

```js
case ADD_RECTANGLE:
  return {
    ...state, 
    rectangles: [...state.rectangles, action.payload],
  }
```

But make sure that `state.rectangles` is always an array and not `undefined` by providing a default initial state argument to the reducer.

```js
function reducer(state={ rectangles: [] }, action) {
```

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense! Really appreciate you taking the time, this caused a lot of headaches haha.

Comment: I wrote that docs page - very glad to see that it's helpful! :)